# How can I pull latest Release and Tags from original project into my forked project in Github?

Tags: git, github

There is a project named A in Github, I fork the project as B.

Now I can pull latest changes from project A and merger them into project B with the Command *Fetch upstream*, you can see Image 1.

But I find the latest Release and Tags of project A aren't pulled into project B, you can see Image 2.

How can I pull latest Release and Tags from original project into my forked project in Github?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: You mean like https://gist.github.com/edrohler/7a0c2ed0db15db768271 ?

Comment: Thanks! But how can I run these code such as "Let [tag] = any tag in upstream repo

git fetch upstream --tags
git push origin --tags" in GitHub

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork to setup two remotes.

Comment: Thanks! Can I pull Tags and Release only in Github website?

Comment: @HelloCW : one question at a time please ; if you have extra needs, please open a new question